# Regex not capturing new lines or quotations when parsing with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex

So, I'm using PHP to try and separate a document into sections. A sample text is below.

```
Preface The idea for this piece of literature came from the Narcotics Anonymous Fellowship itself.

~~~Preface~~~

Step One

"We admitted we were powerless over our addiction, that our lives had become unmanageable." 

~~~Step One~~~
```

What I need is **ANY** text before the `~~~` symbol I need inserted into an array. The array should have the **key** of whatever is between the `~~~` symbols. I also would like to make sure to capture all new lines and quotation marks. However I'm not 100% sure this is possible.

Basically I'm using the `~~~` symbols as breaks in the text. The document is around 96 pages long. So, I'm hoping to eventually be able to then put the results into separate text files with the name equal to the key in the array and the value as content in said text file.

Example:

```
$array = [
    'Preface' => 'Preface The idea for this piece of literature came from the Narcotics Anonymous Fellowship itself.',
    'Step One' => 'Step One\n\"We admitted we were powerless over our addiction, that our lives had become unmanageable.\"'
]
```

I'm stuck because I'm not capturing new lines or quotation marks.

Comment: Do you really want `Preface` in the value as well as the key?

Comment: Yes. I want to match literally EVERYTHING before the "break". I don't care what it is. Same goes for the "Step One" as well. I don't care if it's in the value as well as the key. The key is defined by me manually in the document before parsing. So i'm defining the key myself. I'll just go through and sanitize everything manually after it's broken down into individual text files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex (with the `s` flag, to allow `.` to match newline) to extract the parts you want. It looks for a minimal amount of text `(.*?)` followed by `~~~`, a section name `([\w ]+)` and `~~~`.

```
(.*?)~~~([\w ]+)~~~
```

We use [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all) to find all matches to this regex in the text (each match beginning immediately after the previous one) and then use [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to combine the section names with their text:

```
preg_match_all('/(.*?)~~~([\w ]+)~~~/s', $text, $matches);
$parts = array_combine($matches[2], $matches[1]);
print_r($parts);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [Preface] => Preface The idea for this piece of literature came from the Narcotics Anonymous Fellowship itself.


    [Step One] => Step One

"We admitted we were powerless over our addiction, that our lives had become unmanageable." 


)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/VTPt5)

Comment: This should work! I did a small test, and it seems to be working, so we'll see!!!! :P

Comment: @J.Robinson good to hear. If you have any control over the document, the regex would be *much* more efficient if the section names did not include spaces in them as it will restrict the amount of backtracking it has to do (in that case you would use just `\w+` instead of `[\w ]+`).

Comment: well, this is only working for the first two sections. It's not doing anything more then two sections. See the pastebin here for a bigger sample size... Seems as though it's breaking... https://pastebin.com/14vYssSZ

Comment: @J.Robinson the format of the text in the pastebin doesn't match what's in the question... I had assumed from your sample data that the first text in the section matched the closing (part enclosed in `~~~`) text. Give me a moment to edit...

Comment: I'm sorry. That was totally my bad. I was trying to basically not bog down people with a bunch of text. Obviously my summarization skills didn't help with the answer to this question. I'm truly sorry. Thank you for the help man!

Comment: @J.Robinson no problem at all. Please see my edit and updated demo and let me know if that solves your problem.